# Upload images in tinymce

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, codeigniter-2, tinymce-4

I have a question...I using jbimages for upload images with editor tinymce, I set the path like this:

```
$config['upload_path'] = '/var/www/blog/content';
```

Server which I use is nginx,the path is corect and I make chmod 777 on the content folder, but when trying to save image I got 404 Not Found nginx/1.1.19.On the apache go ok,images are charged...Help me please.I don't understand where is the problem.Exists a solution?Where is the problem?

Comment: what does `$this->upload->display_errors()` output when you try to save the image?

Comment: I select the image after is write Upload in progress and when I push View script's output 404 Nginx not found

Comment: are you setting it in hosting server ?

Comment: can you try with /home/{your hosting user name}/public_html/blog/content

Comment: did you replace {your hosting user name} by your user_name

Comment: Yes...I think is from nginx the error, because in apache works fine

Comment: Is there a screenshot of your error that you can add to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have defined the base url in config file if not that go to your config file and in that you will see the base url, set it like :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

and use the code as follows:

```
$config['upload_path'] = base_url().'/path/to/your/file';
```